# typeorm migration with nestjs and postgres "error: database "admin" does not exist"

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, database-migration, typeorm

please help me.. I'm following [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8810#issuecomment-1156345511) instruction to do migrations in nestjs using typeORM but its always return an error. These my codes:

> .env

```
POSTGRES_HOST = localhost
POSTGRES_PORT = 5432
POSTGRES_USERNAME = postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = pass123
POSTGRES_DATABASE = postgres
```

> ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { cwd } from 'process';

dotenv.config();

export const dataSource = new DataSource ({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: [cwd() + 'src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [cwd() + 'src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
  synchronize: false,
  dropSchema: false,
});
```

> package.json

```
 "scripts": {
        ....
        "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/config/ormconfig.ts",
        "migration:create": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
        "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
        "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
        "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert",
        "schema:sync": "npm run typeorm -- schema:sync"
        }
```

when i try to run the command at the first time using this comand

```
npm run migration:generate --name:CofffeeRefactor
```

i got the error message that there is no role admin

> error: role "admin" does not exist

so i created the role admin in postgresql with this command

```
CREATE ROLE admin WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'pass123' SUPERUSER;
```

I checked

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

so I try it again to generate the migration, but i got the error message that there is no admin database

> error: database "admin" does not exist

what should i do now? please help me figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks likely that you have at least one previous migration failed or all previous migrations doesn't match with your current database schema.

Comment: Yes i did a several trial to do migration with diferent reference before, but all the trial were failed.. after you mention about that, i decide to create a new nest project then start over the migration and it work like a charm. Thankyou so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your environment variables are not being loaded and typeorm is trying to use a default connection.

Since you are using NestJs you can use the ConfigModule to load your environment. This is how I setup mine:

`ormconfig.ts`:

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import postgresMasterConfig from './postgres.config';

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'local';

ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true,
  load: [postgresMasterConfig],
  envFilePath: `env/env.${ENV}`, // If you don't specify envFilePath it will use your .env file
});

export const connectionSource = new DataSource(postgresMasterConfig() as DataSourceOptions);
```

`postgres.config`:

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { join } from 'path';

export default registerAs('database', () => ({
  name: 'default',
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: false,
  logging: process.env.DATABASE_ENABLE_LOGGING === 'true',
  entities: [join(__dirname, '../synchronizer/models/**/*.entity.{ts,js}')],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? '../database/tests/*.ts' : '../database/migrations/*.ts')],
  seeds: [join(__dirname, '../database/seeds/**/*.{ts,js}')],
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
}));
```

For me the benefits of setting it up like this is to allow me to access specific aspects of the configuration from the NestJs `ConfigService` that you can inject somewhere else to access your configuration.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and giving me another way to setup migration. i really appreciate that.